# glmnet predict method throwing cryptic error

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to make a prediction using `glmnet`, and getting a very cryptic error message. 
I have not encountered this before when using `glmnet`, and Googling for the error was not fruitful. The error happens when the last line is un-commented.

```
library(ISLR)
library(glmnet)


Hitters=na.omit(Hitters)
Hitters$Salary = log(Hitters$Salary)

Hitters.train = Hitters[1:200,]
Hitters.test = Hitters[201:dim(Hitters)[1],]

x=model.matrix(Salary~.,Hitters)[,-1]
cv.out=cv.glmnet(x, Hitters$Salary, alpha=0)
bestlam=cv.out$lambda.min
ridge.mod=glmnet(x, Hitters$Salary, alpha=0,lambda=bestlam)

newx = data.matrix(Hitters.test)
#ridge.pred=predict(ridge.mod,s=bestlam,newx=newx)
```

Error output:

```
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: methods
Loaded glmnet 1.9-5

Error in as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error in t(.Call(Csparse_dense_crossprod, y, t(x))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error: Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90
Calls: %*% -> %*% -> t
Calls: predict ... predict.elnet -> NextMethod -> predict.glmnet -> as.matrix
Execution halted
```

Note that changing `newx = data.matrix(Hitters.test)`
to `newx = model.matrix(Salary~.,Hitters.test)` did not help.

As requested, here is the output of `sessionInfo()` before running.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Here is the output after running:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] glmnet_1.9-5 Matrix_1.1-0 ISLR_1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-23
```

Comment: would like to see results of `sessionInfo()`.  Some small chance this is due to a recent update of the `Matrix` package, or a mismatch between `Matrix` and `glmnet` versions ... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I must `NULL` out the response. The following works without error:

```
library(ISLR)
library(glmnet)


Hitters=na.omit(Hitters)
Hitters$Salary = log(Hitters$Salary)

Hitters.train = Hitters[1:200,]
Hitters.test = Hitters[201:dim(Hitters)[1],]

x=model.matrix(Salary~.,Hitters)[,-1]
cv.out=cv.glmnet(x, Hitters$Salary, alpha=0)
bestlam=cv.out$lambda.min
ridge.mod=glmnet(x, Hitters$Salary, alpha=0,lambda=bestlam)

Hitters.test$Salary <- NULL
newx = data.matrix(Hitters.test)
ridge.pred=predict(ridge.mod,s=bestlam,newx=newx)
```

Comment: Aren;t you deleting a whole column of your input data.frame this way? How will it let you use  the resulting matrix (missing the Salary column) in the subsequent predict function? All the variables need to match...

Comment: @theforestecologist, I'm sorry but I don't have enough context for this question anymore since it's been too long.

Comment: I'll just comment that my solution to this problem was to manually set the levels of my x variable factors to be the same between my initial training data and my test data.